# Why silent install mode seems to be rarely taken into account?

Tags: linux

I'm very surprised that even in Linux World, Silent Install is rarely taken into account; a few days ago I was looking for virtual pc vhd silent install and microsoft didn't have.

I'm now looking for Cygwin, all I can find is hack here
http://www.mail-archive.com/unattended-info@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01060.html

Why install is so neglected by authors / software editors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most Unix variants, programs are *always* installed "silently". Most Linux distributions and BSD descendants have a "package manager" program, which takes care of installation by just extracting all files from a package to standard locations, without asking anything. (One exception is Debian with its post-installation `debconf`, but it too can be skipped.)

But Cygwin is *not* "Linux world". It is just an emulation layer of certain Unix (not Linux`*`) features, along with a collection of popular Unix programs compiled to run on that emulation layer.

Cygwin's `setup.exe` is *not* "Linux world" either. It is a pure *Windows* program - an installer - [and a very poor one, at that](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2004-12/msg00019.html).

(Every other installer tool for Windows *does* have a silent mode, although its activation varies; `/s` and `/silent` switches are common.)

`*` *Linux is one Unix-like operating system out of many. There is *BSD, Mac OS X, Solaris, Hurd... While Cygwin may be considered an Unix environment, I certainly would not call it "Linux".*

Comment: Windows has silent install mode with msi but nearly nobody cares. If Cygwin did use MSI instead of using their own bad stuff life would have been better.